# itfoxtex saml mvccore, attribute replace NameID

Tags: asp.net-core, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I cannot figure out how to get an attribute from the the saml response in place of the NameID value.
My IDP team is returning the value I need in an attribute rather than in NameID(which they wont budge on).

Thanks for any help!

I am running MVC Core. I have everything setup and running for NameID from the example 'TestWebAppCore' for ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.

I am trying to get this value in place of NameID for the session username:

```
saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:Attribute Name="valueName"

NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"
                        >
            <saml:AttributeValue>IDValue</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>

[Route("AssertionConsumerService")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
    {
        var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();

        var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

        binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
        if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success) {
            throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
        }

        binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), 
saml2AuthnResponse);
        try {
            await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, 
claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => 
ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            log.writeLog(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
        var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) 
? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably not possible to logout without the NameID but you can login without.

In .NET the NameID is translated into the `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` claim. The users claims is handled in the `ClaimsTransform.CreateClaimsPrincipal` method.

You can either translate the incoming custom claim `"valueName"` to a `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` claim:

```
private static ClaimsPrincipal CreateClaimsPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>();

    claims.AddRange(GetSaml2LogoutClaims(incomingPrincipal));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, GetClaimValue(incomingPrincipal, "valueName")));

    return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, incomingPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType, ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ClaimTypes.Role)
    {
        BootstrapContext = ((ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity).BootstrapContext
    });
}
```

Or change the identity claim in the `ClaimsIdentity` to the incoming  custom claim `"valueName"`:

```
private static ClaimsPrincipal CreateClaimsPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>();

    // All claims
    claims.AddRange(incomingPrincipal.Claims);

    return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, incomingPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType, "valueName", ClaimTypes.Role)
    {
        BootstrapContext = ((ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity).BootstrapContext
    });
}
```

Comment: I just resolved this last night. Your option 1 translating valueName to NameIdentifier was exactly what I did once I realized that portion. Thank's very much for your response to verify!